# How come when I add a blog entry the date appears in my page and database as all zeros - why is this?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, blogs

I also have a date field in my database with a date data type that's not set to null

Here is my view - should there be something additional I should be putting in here?

```
 foreach($blogs AS $viewData)
  {
$id = $viewData->id;
$title = $viewData->title;
$body = $viewData->body;
$username = $viewData->username;
$date = $viewData->date;

?>

   <b> <?=$title?></b>
    <p><?=$body?></p>

      <p>posted by:<?=$username?></p>
      <p>date: <?=$date?></p>

<hr>
```

Here is the function in my model where I insert into the database...

```
   public function insert_entry()
{
    $this->title = $this->input->post('title');
        $this->body = $this->input->post('text');
        $this->username = $this->session->userdata('username'); 
        $this->date = time();// is there something I should change here?

        $this->db->insert('blogs', $this);

     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how do you insert into your blogs table? show query

you should use something like this to have proper values in 'date' field:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO blogs(title,body,username,date) VALUES('$title','$body','$username',NOW())");
```

or if you want to set manual timestamp do something like this:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO blogs(title,body,username,date) VALUES('$title','$body','$username','".date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $your_timestamp)."')");
```

this is the way to insert proper date/datetime values

Comment: Please see my edited question. I have entered what I have in my model..I tried putting in date("Y-m-d H:i:s") instead of time(); but instead i got the date 1970-01-01 why is this?